# Iterating through min and max dates in bash by month

Tags: bash, iteration

What is the easiest way to just generate an iteration that outputs `%Y-%m*` strings from a min and max date values in the form '%Y-%m-%d`? I am able to get min and max dates from my file system with

```
ST_DT=${6-`hdfs dfs -ls  /filepath/key=* | head -2 | tail -1 | cut -d '/' -f6 | cut -d '=' -f2`}
EN_DT=${5-`hdfs dfs -ls /filepath/key=* | tail -1 | cut -d '/' -f6 | cut -d '=' -f2`}
```

which does give me for example:

```
2018-01-01
2018-03-07
```

and I would like to just be able to generate:
`2018-01*`...`2018-02*`...`2018-03*`...etc

Final answer thanks to @anubhava:

```
while [[ $(date +%s -d $i) -le $endt ]]; do
   yr=`date --date "$i" +%Y`
   mth=`date --date "$i" +%m`
   echo "$yr-$mth*"
   i=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d' -d "$i +1 month")
done
```

Comment: what's the output of `hdfs dfs -ls  /filepath/key=* | head -2` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this shell loop using `gnu date`:

```
ST_DT='2018-01-01'
EN_DT='2018-03-07'
endt=$(date '+%s' -d "$EN_DT")
i="$ST_DT"

while [[ $(date +%s -d $i) -le $endt ]]; do
   echo "${i%-*}*"
   i=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d' -d "$i +1 month")
done
```

```
2018-01*
2018-02*
2018-03*
```

Comment: This works with GNU `date` but not the versions in macOS, *BSD, Solaris, etc. While this is a solution implemented in bash, it's not a bash solution.

Comment: Right, I emphasized `gnu date` in answer.

Comment: Thanks. however I need to print out `2018-01*..2018-02*..2018-03*`

Comment: nevermind. that was simple enough to adjust. thank you for the help. Updated my final solution

Comment: on macos do a `brew install coreutils` and replace instances of `date` with `gdate`